# How to test if WindowStaysOnTopHint flag is set in windowFlags?

Tags: python, pyqt, bit-manipulation, flags, always-on-top

Is this supposed to return a boolean value?

```
>>> win.windowFlags() & QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
<PyQt4.QtCore.WindowFlags object at 0x7ad0578>
```

I already knew that

```
# enable always on top
win.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

# disable it
win.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

# toggle it 
win.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WindowFlags` object is an OR'd together set of flags from the `WindowType` enum. The `WindowType` is just a subclass of `int`, and the `WindowFlags` object also supports `int` operations.

You can test for the presence of a flag like this:

```
>>> bool(win.windowFlags() & QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
False
```

or like this:

```
>>> int(win.windowFlags() & QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) != 0
False
```

In general, `&` returns the value itself when present, or zero when absent:

```
>>> flags = 1 | 2 | 4
>>> flags
7
>>> flags & 2
2
>>> flags & 8
0
```